# Adding an outlet to a switch box

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I want to add a hot outlet to a light switch box. The power comes into the light and then down to the switch. How should I be adding the outlet in this scenario? This is also old wiring so it is not 3 wire cables.

Comment: Conduit or cable?

Comment: Cable. I can run another cable down from the light to the outlet if needed. Just didn’t want to pull cable if it wasn’t needed.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this would be to replace the 14/2 or 12/2 with a 14,12/3 cable. At the ceiling connect your new black to hot, new white to existing white and white from light fixture, and red to the black from the light. At the switch box, pigtail hot to brass screw of outlet and to top of switch or follow directions on box if using combination switch/outlet. Connect white to silver screw on outlet and red wire to bottom of switch or follow directions if using combination switch/outlet. Don't use any backstabs if present. Turn off breaker before doing any work.

Answer (score 0):

To have both a light switch and outlet in the same box use a combined switch and outlet

[image]

Comment: *swiff*  OP is describing a switch loop.

Comment: Yes, this device won't work without additional wiring. Harper previously pointed out this is a switch loop, so no neutral for the outlet is available.

Comment: I don't get the DV. This was answered before OP edited question.  Make comments, don't DV.+